# Dijit toolbar button - show text below the button

Tags: button, icons, toolbar, dojo

I have a Dijit toolbar with a set of buttons on it.  And I realise these buttons can be made up of both an icon and text.  However the text only appears to be able to be shown to the left or the right of the icon.  Is there any way the text can be displayed below the icon?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post an example of the current toolbar and button setup on http://jsfiddle.net? The more context, the easier it will be to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you're still looking for an answer. I had a Dijit toolbar with some buttons. These buttons had icons in the form of `<img>` tags and some text. Adding a simple `<br />` between the `<img>` and the text did the trick for me.